# Receiving Touch Events from a Service (Solution?)

Tags: android, service, touch-event

So, earlier I posted a question about receiving touch events from a service (apparently no one knows the answer).

After trying to figure it out myself for hours, I gave up and decided to email a developer known as RubberBigPepper. I asked him how he did it in his app Volume control and he promptly responded "**TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT window**".

What does this mean, and how can it be implemented in code?

EDIT:

I used the following method:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

and the window failed to receive touch events.

I emailed him about this as well and he says: "Use the WindowService to add your window"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use code like this.

```
int nFlags=WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;       
             m_cWM=(WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
             WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                nFlags,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
m_cWM.addView(YourViewClass, lp);
```

And don't forget about uses-permissions

Comment: Here is what I have: TextView tv = new TextView(this); tv.setText("Hello"); 
  int nFlags=WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;       
        m_cWM=(WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(...)  m_cWM.addView(tv, lp); - but the textview only appears within the activity. When i navigate home, it disappears and the device stops registering touches.

Comment: Fortunately, this no longer works on newer versions of Android. You can receive the touch events, but you then consume them, and the underlying app does not receive them.