# Is launching a view from a service as depicted safe or will it likely become blocked in a future API

Tags: android

It seems Android is steadily becoming more and more locked down.  Curious if the marked solution in the post below is safe to do or just more code destined to stop working.  I also wasn't sure if CommonsWare was eluding to the fact that it already is.

[Receiving Touch Events from a Service (Solution?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322188/receiving-touch-events-from-a-service-solution)

Answer (score 0):

> Curious if the marked solution in the post below is safe to do or just more code destined to stop working.

That is impossible for anyone without a working time machine to answer.

> I also wasn't sure if CommonsWare was eluding to the fact that it already is.

Well, actually, that comment may have been related to something else no longer there (e.g., a deleted comment) or is a bit of a *non sequitur*. I do that sometimes.

Back in Android 1.x/2.x, it was possible for a "tapjacking" attack using the outlined technique, where both your app got the touch events *and* the app your `View` floats over also getting the touch events. This was a security flaw, and I (and plenty of others) vented about it to Google.

In Android 4.0, they blocked the tapjacking attack by no longer passing the touch events down if they are exposed to the floating `View`. So, if your `View` gets the touch events, the app beneath you does not. Or, if your `View` does not get the touch events (display only), then the underlying app can get them (akin to a `Toast`). That's what I was referring to in my comment.

I have no idea whether Google is happy, sad, indifferent, or oblivious to the rise of apps doing this whole floating-views-over-other-apps stuff. I am reasonably hopeful that if other security flaws are found related to this, that Google will lock things down more. Whether they would do so in a way that totally breaks this technique or could make a more surgical fix is also impossible to say at this time.

On the whole, I'd say that this technique is safer than most reflection-based "hey, let's hack the `@hide` stuff" tricks you see, but it is more risky than, say, writing a regular `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on point 2.  On point 1.  I realize Google's a black box and nobody really knows.  I was looking for maybe a best guess based on their past behavior, based on the target code here, especially using system-based window types, like TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR which people really seem to think is a bad idea and are only reserved for the "system".  I can't use an activity by the way as I need the underlying activity to not pause.